# Multi-key Map in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, hashmap, key, scala-collections

How can I create a Map in Scala which does not only take a single parameter as key, but rather two or three.

```
val map = //..?
map("abc", 1) = 1
println(map("abc", 2)) // => null
println(map("abc", 1)) // => 1
```

I tried using tuples as a key, but then I have to assign values like this

```
map(("abc", 1)) = 1
```

Can I somehow get rid of the inner parentheses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add your own enhancement to `Map` that will do the trick:

```
import collection.mutable.Map

implicit class EnhancedMap[A,B,C](m: Map[(A,B),C]) {
  def update(a: A, b: B, c: C) { m((a,b)) = c }
}
```

then

```
val map = Map(("abc", 1) -> 0)
map("abc", 1) = 1
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 12):

You could also use

```
map += ("abc", 1) -> 1
```

If the map key represents something (e.g. user info) and if you want to add clarity to your code (especially if you have 3 elements in the key), I would go with a case class as the key. Case classes have equals and hashcode implemented so you can safely use them as keys in a map. The code would be more verbose though:

```
case class MapKey(s: String, i: Int, d: Double)

val map = Map[MapKey, X](MapKey("a", 1, 1.1) -> "value1", MapKey("b", 2, 2.2) -> "value2")

val map2 = map + (MapKey("c", 3, 3.3) -> "value3")

//or for mutable map
map(MapKey("d", 4, 4.4)) = "value4"
//or
map += MapKey("e", 5, 5.5) -> "value5"
```

Comment: Yes, thought about using case classes as well, but that is even more noisy than the brackets.

Comment: I agree that case classes increase the verbosity of the code in this case. They would allow to better type your map and add clarity to the code because you can name the concept that the key represent. But depending on you use case, they can also be overkill.

Comment: Problem with this is you cannot search properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use -> syntax for tuples:

```
map("abc" -> 1) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I got compiling errors using Luigi Plinge's approach. The following approach works for me, which is simpler.

```
scala> var b = Map[(Int, Int), Int]()
b: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),Int] = Map()

scala> b = b + ((1,1)->2)
b: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),Int] = Map((1,1) -> 2)

scala> b
res15: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),Int] = Map((1,1) -> 2)

scala> b = b + ((1,2)->2)
b: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),Int] = Map((1,1) -> 2, (1,2) -> 2)

scala> b(1,1)
res16: Int = 2

scala> b(1,2)
res17: Int = 2
```